# Abort Called in program for printing the next lexicographical permutation of a string

Tags: c, string

Here is my code, it takes as input an integer s which is the number of strings I want it to process and then it takes s strings as input. For each of them it should output a greater lexicographical permutation of the letters, the smallest one. The problem is that it compiles fine, but at runtime it crashes and I really don't know why. Any suggestion?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 int compare(const void *a, const void * b);
 void swap(char* a, char* b);
 int findCeil (char* str, char first, int l, int h);
 void nextPermutation(char* w);


int main(void){
    int s;
    char* w;
    scanf("%d", &s);
    while(s--){
        w = (char*)malloc(sizeof(101));
        if(w == NULL){ printf("Malloc failed.\n"); return 1;}
        scanf("%s", w);
        nextPermutation(w);
        free(w);
    }
    return 0;
}


//function for qsort()
int compare(const void *a, const void * b){
  return ( *(char *)a - *(char *)b );
}

//utility function 
void swap(char* a, char* b){
    char t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

/* This function finds the index of the smallest character
    which is greater than 'first' and is present in str[l..h]*/
int findCeil (char str[], char first, int l, int h){
    int ceilIndex = l;
    int i;
    // find the smallest character greater than first
    for (i = l+1; i <= h; ++i)
      if (str[i] > first && str[i] < str[ceilIndex])
            ceilIndex = i;
    return ceilIndex;
}

void nextPermutation(char* w){
    int size = strlen(w);
    int i;    
    // Find the rightmost character which is smaller than its next
    // character. Let us call it 'first char'        
    for(i = size - 2; i >= 0; --i){
        if(w[i] < w[i+1])
            break; 
    }
    // If there is no such chracter, all are sorted in decreasing order, 
    //it means we are done.
    if(i == -1)
        printf("no answer\n");
    else{
        int ceilIndex = findCeil(w, w[i], i + 1, size - 1 );     
        // Swap first and second characters
        swap( &w[i], &w[ceilIndex] );
        // Sort the string on right of 'first char'
        qsort( w + i + 1, size - i - 1, sizeof(w[0]), compare );
        printf("%s\n", w);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it won't compile perfectly without the explicit cast on malloc(), then you're not actually programming in C. Also, where is `t` declared? main() won't even compile.

Comment: I think you wanted `malloc(101);` instead of `malloc(sizeof(101));`. The former allocates 101 bytes while the latter allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes. BTW, don't cast the result of `malloc` and family

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a trivial thing at the end. Some times after staring a thing for too long you become blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `sizeof(101)` return?

Hint:  it's not 101...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you tried using `malloc(sizeof(101))`. When using it, it actually allocating you a memory of `int` size which is probably not what you meant. 
I guess you meant `malloc(sizeof("101"))` since you convert it later to `char*`. Or perhaps you wanted use `malloc(101)` to get an exact memory size.

Comment: I meant `malloc(101)`